# How do I move a spark dataframe's columns to a nested column in the same dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My approach to move a spark dataframe's columns to a nested column within the same dataframe is something like this:

```
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

  val data = Seq(("Adam", "111", "50000"),
                 ("Abe", "222", "60000"),
                 ("Sam", "333", "40000"))

  var df = data.toDF("Name", "EmpId__c", "Salary__c")
  df.show(false)

  val cstColsSeq = df.columns.filter(c => c.endsWith("__c")).map(f => { col(f) }).toSeq
  var cstMapCol: Column = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct(cstColsSeq)
  df = df.withColumn("cstMap", cstMapCol)
```

The issue is that I can't provide a Seq[Column] to org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct(...) call. It only accepts a Column* param.

A follow through was to do something like this:

```
for (i <- cstColsList) {
    cstMapCol = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct(i)
    df = df.withColumn("cstMap", cstMapCol)
}
```

however, this overrides the `cstMap`

Any thoughts how do I supply cstColsSeq to the struct ? Also open to other solutions which might take a different approach of adding nesting columns in an existing populated dataframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the `Seq` using the `: _*` notation:

```
var cstMapCol: Column = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct(cstColsSeq: _*)
```

which will give the output

```
df.withColumn("cstMap", cstMapCol).show
+----+--------+---------+------------+
|Name|EmpId__c|Salary__c|      cstMap|
+----+--------+---------+------------+
|Adam|     111|    50000|[111, 50000]|
| Abe|     222|    60000|[222, 60000]|
| Sam|     333|    40000|[333, 40000]|
+----+--------+---------+------------+
```